# Compiling Ada with GCC

Tags: gcc, ada

I'm trying to compile this `Calculator.ada` file using `gcc -c Calculator.ada` and receive the error `warning: Calculator.ada: linker input file unused because linking not done` -- I've tried looking up solutions and downloading other things that may compile this for me but haven't figured it out yet....

Here is `Calculator.ada`:

```
--
-- Integer calculator program.  Takes lines of input consisting of
-- <operator> <number>, and applies each one to a display value.  The
-- display value is printed at each step.  The operator is one of =,
-- +, -, *, /, or ^, which correspond to assign, add, subtract, multiply
-- divide, and raise, respectively.  The display value is initially zero.
-- The program terminates on a input of q.
--
with Text_IO;
with Gnat.Io; use Gnat.Io;
procedure Calc is
   Op: Character;               -- Operation to perform.
   Disp: Integer := 0;          -- Contents of the display.
   In_Val: Integer;             -- Input value used to update the display.
begin
   loop
      -- Print the display.
      Put(Disp);
      New_Line;

      -- Promt the user.
      Put("> ");

      -- Skip leading blanks and read the operation.
      loop
         Get(Op);
         exit when Op /= ' ';
      end loop;

      -- Stop when we're s'posed to.
      exit when Op = 'Q' or Op = 'q';

      -- Read the integer value (skips leading blanks) and discard the
      -- remainder of the line.
      Get(In_Val);
      Text_IO.Skip_Line;

      -- Apply the correct operation.
      case Op is
         when '='      => Disp := In_Val;
         when '+'      => Disp := Disp + In_Val;
         when '-'      => Disp := Disp - In_Val;
         when '*'      => Disp := Disp * In_Val;
         when '/'      => Disp := Disp / In_Val;
         when '^'      => Disp := Disp ** In_Val;
         when '0'..'9' => Put_Line("Please specify an operation.");
         when others   => Put_Line("What is " & Op & "?");
      end case;
   end loop;
end Calc;
```

I would appreciate any assistance as to why I can't compile this. I'm able to compile C files fine with `gcc -c` and read that I can compile the same way for Ada.

Comment: It didn't compile though, or am I missing something @EugeneSh. ? I sitll only have the .ada, shouldn't there/that have produced a .o?

Comment: Given [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Running-a-Simple-Ada-Program.html), ADA program should have an extension `adb` or `ads`. It could be the case `gcc` just doesn't understand it is an ADA program...

Comment: Type "gnat --version" ... if you get "command not found" your gcc installation is incomplete, you'll have to find and install the Ada parts of it (usually a package called "gnat-<version>. Then "gnatmake Calculator.adb" (rename the file!) should compile and link it(and all its dependencies)

Answer (score 6):

Since gcc only recognizes `.ads` and `.adb` as file endings for Ada sources (as explained in [this link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Running-a-Simple-Ada-Program.html) mentioned by Eugene), you need to tell it explicitly that you want this file to be compiled as Ada source. You can do this via

```
gcc -x ada -c Calculator.ada
```

The compiler will then probably give a warning like

```
Calculator.ada:11:11: warning: file name does not match unit name, should be "calc.adb"
```

but you can ignore that. However, best practice would be to use the file names expected by gcc.

Comment: I'm receiving the `no such file` exists error for it now

Comment: Well you are not showing your full code. You import a package `Text_IO` which is not standard (there only is a package `Ada.Text_IO`). The error may well be in the interface of that package and you need to show its code.

Answer (score 3):

By default, Ada source file need to end with `.ads` (for package specs) or `.adb` (for bodies), and file names need to match the top-level entity they contain.  In your case, you should use `calc.adb`.

If you have more complex source files containing multiple entities, you can use the [`gnatchop` tool to rename source files](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Renaming-Files-with-gnatchop.html).

Under [File Naming Topics and Utilities](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/File-Naming-Topics-and-Utilities.html), the manual contains much more documentation how source code can be represented in the file system.

Comment: I did read about that, and I changed my file to exactly that: `Calc.adb` and tried to compile the same way - I now/then received the error: `gcc: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory`

Comment: Could it be your `gcc` doesn't have the ADA support? It is not obvious it has.

Comment: It's `calc.adb` (lower case). Regarding the `CreateProcess` error, that's quite odd. It's not something that FSF GCC would print. Are you using the AdaCore distribution?

Comment: @FlorianWeimer I think, if gcc (the compiler driver) can't find or spawn a process for the compiler itself (gcc1, gnat1 etc) this CreateProcess error is what results.

Comment: Ada source files can be named anything at all. However, GNAT, a specific Ada compiler, unless explicitly told otherwise, expects a file to contain only a single compilation unit and be named the unit name, in lower case, with '.' replaced by '-', and end in .ads or .adb.